# Scope of function parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

I'm trying to make some jQuery functions a little easier to implement and so I tried to encapsulate some autocomplete logic into a function to allow a user to send in a variable of the URL, the parameter of the web service and the control whose value we need to take. With the following script I get the error: `response is not defined`.  The idea is that in this web service there will be many different methods which have autocomplete functionality and I can simply pass the name of the appropriate method and its parameter to the `Complete` method and have the functionality on multiple text boxes.
Why is it that

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
        {

            $('#auto').autocomplete(
            {

                source: function (request, response)
                {
                    Complete('GetNames', 'hospitalName', '#auto');
                }
            });
            function Complete(url, varName, target)
            {
                $.ajax(
                    {

                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Service.asmx/" + url,
                        data: "{'" + varName + "':'" + $(target).val() + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            //uncaught reference error response is not defined
                            response(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr)
                        {
                            console.log(xhr.status);
                        }
                    });
            }

        });
```

This was working fine before I tried to take out the AJAX call and make it its own method.  I'd like to know

1. the source function is calling the Complete function and the source function has `request` and `response` as parameters, so why are they undefined in my script?
2. how can I fix this and avoid future problems in #1.

Comment: The scope of parameters is the just that function body. Since `Complete` is not within the body of the `source:` function, `response` is out of scope.

Comment: So it doesn't matter then that Complete is called within the scope of source? Hm.. more reading to do.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between _lexical_ scope and _dynamic_ scope. JS uses lexical scoping, which means the scope refers to the textual body of the function.

Comment: @Barmar yep.  Now that I know what the name is, I know what to look for.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously it was working because the variable `response` was available in the closure scope of the ajax success callback method. Since you created a separate method now the ajax callback is not within the closure scope of the source method so you need to pass the `request` and `response` parameters as arguments to the `Complete` method

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#auto').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            Complete(request, response, 'GetNames', 'hospitalName', '#auto');
        }
    });

    function Complete(request, response, url, varName, target) {
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "Service.asmx/" + url,
            data: "{'" + varName + "':'" + $(target).val() + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                //uncaught reference error response is not defined
                response(data.d);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: I know a tiny bit about closures (I think).  From what I understand a closure allows you to get a variables value outside of the scope of a function.  Is this correct?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie not outside the scope of the function, a variable declared in a function will be available in functions which is defined within the outer function. Read more in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by passing the values to `Complete`, as in Arun P Johny's answer. You can also make `Complete` a closure within the `source:` function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#auto').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            Complete('GetNames', 'hospitalName', '#auto');
            function Complete(url, varName, target) {
                var data = [];
                data[varname] = $(target).val();
                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Service.asmx/" + url,
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Since it's nested within that function, it has access to its local variables.

However, if the reason you pulled the AJAX code outside the `source:` option in the first place was because you wanted to be able to call it from other places (so you can pass different URLs, targets, or variable names), this won't work -- the function is only accessible from within that function.

P.S. Don't try to construct your own JSON that way, use `JSON.stringify()` as I showed.

Comment: You are correct, the reason why I tried to isolate the AJAX call was to make it easier to call from other places.  I envisioned something like control.Complete(`parameters`).  I'm glad I asked instead of trying to do something that was impossible for half the afternoon.  Gratzie.